# Recover corrupted file after power outage

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project for a customer. While I have edited the code, I had a power outage in the whole home. When my computer back I tried to open the main php file , but I get weird null symbols..

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV5Eg.png) describes my problem:

[image]

I am really out of time and do not what to do. Hope to get a little help.

Comment: Restore from your version control system.

Comment: I have tried doing it for 2 diffrent points of restores but it didn't help..

Comment: @OP: Not from windows restore points. From version control points. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control for more information.

Comment: If this is a *nix OS, you may have a file called `filename.php~` in your work directory.

Answer (score 1):

Restore a working copy of it from your version control system (Mercurial, Git, SVN, what have you.)

If you don't use one, [you *really* should be doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658/getting-started-with-version-control). In the meantime, check your IDE's cache. Some IDEs keep local copies of your files to compare differences between saves.

Failing that, you'll need to use file/drive recovery software--although the chances of it recovering your file is slim (slim enough to consider it 'gone'.)